# I need to scan a file for special characters

Tags: linux, character

I'm working in a postgres linux environment. My locale is UTF-8. I periodically get a load file that is read as a binary charset, and my system can't process it. In most cases, I can pull the file back, save it as 'unicode (.txt) in excel, import it and it will load fine, but in some cases, something in the file is still triggering the 'binary' charset.

I keep treating the symptoms, but what I really need is a way to scan the file for any offending characters. I've not found a way to effectively do this yet.

Ultimately, the only command that has been provided for this purpose is as follows, but this provides no output.

grep -avx '.*' BLAH_import_BLAH.txt

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. How dows your "load file" look like? Is it a CSV file? How exactly do you process it? What commands do you use? What error message do you get? Can you show the difference between a problematic file and the file after you fixed it? What software on what OS is used to create the files with wrong encoding? What language setting(s) do the systems have?

Comment: `.*` matches everything, because you put `-v`, which provided no output.